# Rails don't showing images from public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

I am making an app - it is uploading (with `carrierwave`) pdf and ppt files, then `Docsplit` extracts pages/slides to images and save it to `public/uploads/document/unique_timestamp/` folder.

In `show` view the images don't show, but links are correct - for example "http://localhost:3000/Users/my_user_name/Documents/rp/1512/my_app/public/uploads/document/1450527696/qwerty_2.jpg" and I see [image]

What can I do?

in controllers/documents_controller.rb:

```
def show
    @output_path = "#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/document/" + @document.image.to_s[-14,10] + "/"
end
```

in view/show.html.erb:

```
<ul>
<% Dir.foreach(@output_path) do |f| %>

  <% if f != "." && f != ".." %>
    <li>
      <%= image_tag @output_path + f %>
      <br><%= f %>
    </li>

  <% end %>

<% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between URL paths and your filesystem paths. Generally, the URL path `/` is mapped to your `public` directory on your computer. As such, when requesting `http://localhost:3000/uploads/document/1450527696/qwerty_2.jpg`, your webserver will serve the file found in `/Users/my_user_name/Documents/rp/1512/my_app/public/uploads/document/1450527696/qwerty_2.jpg`.

In your code, you have to use the two different paths in their reqpective locations, i.e. the filesystem path when getting the available files and the URL path when generating the `image_tag`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I don't understand that it is necessary to change in my code?))

Answer (score 0):

Remove `public` from your URL and try:

```
http://localhost:3000/uploads/document/1450527696/qwerty_2.jpg
```